# A valid location could not be found for the breakpoint, in eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I'm working on a javascript project in eclipse, and out of no where I am getting this error message whenever I try to set a breakpoint anywhere: A valid location could not be found for the breakpoint. I was able to set breakpoints just fine before.

I cleaned all my projects, restarted eclipse, refreshed my workspace, restarted the debugger, but nothing works. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and tell the Eclipse version and which plugins you are using for JavaScript. Have you recently installed additional plugins? Can you reproduce the problem with a fresh workspace?